# Regex/PHP, missmatched end

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to get 3 matches of a string like this one, seperated by colons:

```
{{text:1:{"a":"b"}}}
```

Desired result:

```
match[1] = text
match[2] = 1
match[3] = {"a":"b"}
```

using the following search-pattern:

```
\{\{(.\*?):(.\*?):(.\*?)\}\}
```

Sadly, the outcome is

```
match[1] = text
match[2] = 1
match[3] = {"a":"b"
```

How can i limit the regex to only search within the outer `{{}}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing the `?`

Like this:
`{{(.*?):(.*?):(.*)}}`

```
Group 1: text

Group 2: 1

Group 3: {"a":"b"}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem in your specific case is the last `?` in the pattern, preventing a greedy match for the third group, so it stops at the first `}}` after the second `:`. As an alternative you could add a `$` to the end (and possibly a `^` to the beginning), if the string to match is always ending (and starting) with double braces.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
$text='{{text:1:{"a":"b"}}}';
preg_match_all("~{{(.*?):(.*?):({.*?})}}~",$text,$match);
print_r($match);

/*output

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => {{text:1:{"a":"b"}}}
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => text
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => {"a":"b"}
        )

)
*/
```